# Optimize like expression in sqlite database query

Tags: sqlite, optimization, sql-like

Is there any possible way to optimize query similiar to that:
`select col_1, col_2 from foo where bar like '%sth%'`?

Unfortunately I need to use both wildcards - at the beginning and in the end. Can I tune SQLite database to run faster queries?

Comment: Do you know what goes between the wildcards before hand? (i.e. is it compile time constant?) Because if you do, you could have an extra column that you set to 1 or 0 depending if the string is in the column or not when you insert the data.

Comment: No. "sth" is value of variable.

Comment: Could http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html help you out?